# How can I download deb from a PPA?

Tags: ppa, repository, deb

How can I download deb package from a PPA?

Comment: Mostly you don't download a package from a PPA. You rather add the PPA to the repositories your package system knows about and install a package via `apt-get`, just like you would do with a package from the standard Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html

Comment: Do you mean "When you are not on Ubuntu" ?

Answer (score 18):

**This is an example to download a deb file.**

This can be done. But it need not be, if you add a PPA to the system.

e.g.:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
```

**But let's go on with the example of downloading.**

Go to the PPA page, e.g. [“Inkscape Developers” team](https://launchpad.net/%7Einkscape.dev)

- Use the link eg. [Inkscape Stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Einkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable)

  [image]
- Use the link [View package details](https://launchpad.net/%7Einkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+packages)

  [image]
- Use the link eg. [inkscape - 0.91.0+47~ubuntu15.04.1](https://launchpad.net/%7Einkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+sourcepub/4773626/+listing-archive-extra)

  [image]
- Use the link eg. [inkscape_0.91.0+47~ubuntu15.04.1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/%7Einkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+files/inkscape_0.91.0%2B47%7Eubuntu15.04.1_amd64.deb)

  [image]

Comment: Beware: this does not download any dependencies, and you will still need to download the dependencies if you are downloading .deb files separately.

Comment: @ThomasW. The question is, how do I download a deb file. In addition, did I mention that it is an unusual plan.

Comment: @ThomasW. Apart from this, the download of a file is a smaller security risk, as adding a PPA.

Comment: You don't explicitly say this is an unusual case.  And with certain assumptions which veterans of this site make, you should also make note of the specific warnings that could go with this, such as ensuring that if the download is destined for offline installation that the ***dependencies*** are also downloaded, and similar warnings.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to "A.B." - this is useful - an easier way is to just construct the URL from the PPA, so for ppa:**inkscape.dev**/***stable***
the URL is:
https://launchpad.net/~**inkscape.dev**/+archive/ubuntu/***stable***/+packages

This gives the list of packages where you can choose the package for your distribution.
You can do this with a script - example: create script ppa.sh containing:

```
echo $* | awk -F/ '{
    sub(".*ppa:","",$0)
    print "https://launchpad.net/~"$1"/+archive/ubuntu/"$2"/+packages"
    }'
```

Any of the following will then work:

```
./ppa.sh inkscape.dev/stable
./ppa.sh ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
./ppa.sh apt-add-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
./ppa.sh sudo apt-add-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
```

to give:
    https://launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+packages

Answer (score 1):

I just needed this too, but wanted an automated way to get the latest version of the .deb, without needing a browser every time.

Here's a full list of commands that you can put in a script and which always gets you the latest version .deb from the phpmyadmin ppa, whatever the latest version is at the time (replace nijel/phpmyadmin with the source of the ppa you're interested in):

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get update
cd /tmp
apt-get download phpmyadmin
sudo add-apt-repository -y -r ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get update
```

You will then have some phpmyadmin*.deb file in /tmp. The above will add and then remove the phpmyadmin ppa source from your system. If you don't want it removed, then just comment the last two lines.